# Is std::exception_ptr thread safe?

Tags: c++, exception, concurrency, thread-safety, race-condition

I have a worker thread that is constantly running, created & managed through a `std::thread`. At the top level of my worker thread, I have a try/catch block with a while loop inside it. If an exception leaks through to the top level of the thread, I catch it and store it in a `std::exception_ptr`, which is a member of the class that also owns the non-static thread function:

```
// In class header (inside class declaration)
std::exception_ptr m_threadException;

// In class CPP file
void MyClass::MyThreadFunction()
{
    try {
        while (true) {
            // Do thread stuff
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        m_threadException = std::current_exception();
    }
}
```

Once the thread dies due to this kind of exception, my class (which is also primarily used by the main thread) doesn't know it yet. My plan was to add thread checkpoints to the start of all the class's main functions, like so:

```
void MyClass::SomethingMainThreadCalls()
{
    if (m_threadException) {
        std::rethrow_exception(m_threadException);
        m_threadException = nullptr; // Somehow reset it back to null; not sure if this will work
    }

    // Do normal function stuff
}
```

Assuming this is even a good idea, there's a possible race condition between when my main thread is checking if the exception_ptr is null (when calling `SomethingMainThreadCalls()`) and when the worker thread assigns to it. I haven't found any information (haven't checked the C++11 draft yet) about whether or not this is inherently thread safe (guaranteed by the standard) or if I am responsible for thread synchronization in this case.

If the latter, is using `std::atomic` a good idea to keep it simple? Example:

```
std::atomic<std::exception_ptr> m_threadException;
```

Something like that? I'd be interested in recommendations and information on best practice here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no special statement about `exception_ptr` with regards to its thread safety in the standard. As such, it provides the default standard guarantee: accessing separate instances are fine, accessing the *same instance* is not.

I would suggest using `atomic<bool>` instead (if for no other reason than that `exception_ptr` is not trivially copyable and therefore can't be put in an `atomic<T>`) to let the other code know that the `exception_ptr` has been set. You'll be fine so long as:

1. You set `m_threadException` *before* setting the flag
2. You read `m_threadException` *after* checking the flag
3. You use the appropriate load/store memory orders to set/check the flag. The defaults are fine
4. You only write `m_threadException` exactly once.

Comment: This is a good idea. It also eliminates the need to set the `exception_ptr` to null. According to cppreference.com, there is no documented interface for `exception_ptr`, so I'm not even sure if it has an assignment operator for `nullptr`.

Comment: @void.pointer: It does have a "documented interface". It says [right there on the site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr): "`std::exception_ptr` meets the requirements of [NullablePointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/NullablePointer)." It even says what the default and copy constructors do. As well as comparison operators.

Comment: Sorry, tunnel vision. I was expecting an actual interface spec on that page, like cppreference.com usually does for other class-types. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't even able to instantiate a `std::atomic<std::exception_ptr>` so this seems to be the only approach (excepting other locking primitives)

Answer (score 3):

The standard doesn't specify what is the implementation of `std::exception_ptr`, so the thread safeness of `std::exception_ptr` is also unspecified.

just wrap the exception pointer with some lock and the code will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just tried to do this, but `std::atomic` requires a trivially copyable type, `std::exception_ptr` is not. You should get compilation error as I do (when using MSVC VS2019, C++14).